# Partial match of the strings in R and get the matched and not matched records

Tags: r, string

I Have an object called `mystring` where I have full length strings that have their partial match in another object called `match.string`. I want to use match.string to bait in mystring and find the full length matched strings as a result. I also want the record of the strings that were matched and not matched in `mystring`.

```
mystring<-c("the_dootle_doo_bottle-doo","no_cuddle-doo_do_bottle-coo","tape-it-ape-it","mac-chicken-no-good")
match.string<-c("the_dootle","no_cuddle-doo","mac", "I-loathe-it","no-way")
```

In the result I want:

```
"the_dootle_doo_bottle-doo" "no_cuddle-doo_do_bottle-coo" "mac-chicken-no-good"
```

Adittionally in the result, I would also like to see the list of strings in match.strings that were matched (`"the_dootle","no_cuddle-doo","mac"`) and not matched (`"I-loathe-it","no-way"`) with the strings in mystring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with:

```
l <- unlist(lapply(match.string, function(txt) mystring[grepl(txt, mystring)]))
```

this gives:

```
> l
[1] "the_dootle_doo_bottle-doo"   "no_cuddle-doo_do_bottle-coo" "mac-chicken-no-good"
```

To get a record of the matched/non-matched ones, you can do:

```
indx <- unlist(lapply(match.string, function(txt) grep(txt, mystring)))
```

this gives an index of the matched strings in `mystring`:

```
> indx
[1] 1 2 4
```

With this index you can then get the matched / non-matched results in `mystring`:

```
> mystring[indx]
[1] "the_dootle_doo_bottle-doo"   "no_cuddle-doo_do_bottle-coo" "mac-chicken-no-good"        
> mystring[-indx]
[1] "tape-it-ape-it"
```

To get the found and non-found items of `match.string` you can do the following (as suggested by [@Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1191259/frank)):

```
indx2 <- sapply(lapply(match.string, agrepl, mystring), any)

> match.string[indx2]
[1] "the_dootle"    "no_cuddle-doo" "mac"          
> match.string[!indx2]
[1] "I-loathe-it" "no-way"
```

As an alternative, you can also use `magrittr` to create the index:

```
library(magrittr)
indx2 <- sapply(match.string, . %>% agrepl(., mystring) %>% any )
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I also get the record of matched and not matched ones. That is where I had problem.

Comment: I actually wanted the found and not found records of match.string

Comment: why do I get this error:Error in unlist(as.matrix(lapply(all.wanted.bam, function(txt) grep(txt,  : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'unlist': Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Comment: I used another method now, see the update. Does this work?

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
mystring[pmatch(match.string,mystring)]

# [1] "the_dootle_doo_bottle-doo"   "no_cuddle-doo_do_bottle-coo" "mac-chicken-no-good"  NA    NA
```